# iPhone and iPod Emulator

Tags: iphone

I intend to write some piece of code for an iPod and an iPhone. so, i'm looking for emulators for those devices.

basically an emulator which will help me test the application I'm writing.

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the answers.
I need to write an application that transfers files from my computer to the iPhone device. is there any simulator I can use for that ?
or should I still use the ones you guyz suggested ? (simulator obtained after registering to Apple).

Answer (score 8):

To develop iPhone apps you need to download the iPhone SDK. This includes the tools and libraries to code you applications as well as a simulator to test your code. This tools are available only for intel macs.

You can get the sdk for free here: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/

To test you code in a real iPhone, you will need to join the iPhone Developer Program (http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/), which is not for free.

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about writing an application or writing code for your website to display properly on an iPhone?

The former requires a developer subscription with Apple to access their SDK and emulator.

For the latter, there seem to be several emulators out there to test your web site, check out:

- http://iphonetester.com/
- http://www.testiphone.com/

A Google search for 'iPhone emulator' should find a lot for you.

Comment: Oddly, neither of these sites appear to work properly. For instance, I would assume that google.com, when accessed via iPhone, would fit on the iphone screen?

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone SDK comes with an iPhone simulator that you can use with Xcode during development.

You can download the SDK from [http://developer.apple.com/iphone](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/) - you need to be a registered iPhone developer, however, although this is free, after which you can use the simulator.

Note that if you want to send your applications to a physical device you need to enrol in the [iPhone developer program](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/program/) which starts at $99.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to actually get an iPhone for that.  You'll have to register the $99 but then you'll get the ability to upload apps to your iPhone/pod.

You could also jailbreak your phone/pod and do whatever you want.

There are also apps available that let you transfer stuff to and from your phone in the appstore (at least one free, if I recall correctly)

If you want to do something more with the files than just transfer them to the phone/pod, it's likely that you'll have to jailbreak your phone/pod anyway.

I keep wanting to find a better abbreviation for typing iPod/iPhone.  How about iP(od/hone)?  Hmm, not better!